Failed to obtain R2DBC connection when running dockerized spring boot application
I am getting Failed to obtain R2DBC connection error message when sending POST request to feed some data into the database.
Here is the docker compose configuration of my microservice2 where I am sending the request:
  microservice2:
    container_name: microservice2
    image: microservice2_layered:latest
    ports:
      - "8002:8002"
    environment:
      - spring.data.r2dbc.repositories.enabled=true
      - eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://discovery-server:8761/eureka
      - SPRING_R2DBC_URL=r2dbc:mysql://mysql:3307/containerdatabase
      - SPRING_R2DBC_USERNAME=root
      - SPRING_R2DBC_PASSWORD=rootpassword
      - SPRING_R2DBC_DRIVER=io.asyncer:r2dbc-mysql
    depends_on:
      discovery-server:
        condition: service_healthy
        restart: true
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
        restart: true
      api-gateway:
        condition: service_healthy
        restart: true
    links:
      - mysql

Configuration for mysql:
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql_container
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - "3307:3307"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=containerdatabase
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpassword
      - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%
      - MYSQL_AUTHENTICATION_PLUGIN=caching_sha2_password
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "-u$MYSQL_USER", "-p$MYSQL_PASSWORD",  "ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 5s

I can see all the discovery clients are registered to the eureka server including Microservice2, but when I send the POST request I get the aforesaid error response in postman. I have created the database called 'containerdatabase' and a table inside it. I also verified that the table exists.
When I run the application in Intellij, it works fine locally but it is not working when running in the docker.
Here is the application.yml configuration for running locally in my machine:
spring:
  application:
    name: microservice2
  r2dbc:
    url: r2dbc:mysql://localhost:3306/deployment_prep
    username: root
    password: Password123
    driver: io.asyncer:r2dbc-mysql

